# Web Application directory mapping

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter, mapping

I'm working on a small web application that contains some JSPs, Servlets and static HTML pages. There are also some filters to implement a small authentication/authorization mechanism. My questions are:

- How can I map an entire directory of JSPs to another? Here's an example: I want to map all the URLs like `localhost:8080/WebAppName/pages/*.jsp` to `localhost:8080/WebAppName/*.jsp` . How can I do that without writing an entry in the web.xml for each JSPs page in the directory 'pages'?
- After having mapped these URLs to new ones, what do I have to write in the  tag of  in the web.xml? The mapped URL (`WebAppName/*.jsp`) or the real one (`WebAppName/pages/*.jsp`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you even need to? I only ever added mappings for servlets, not for JSPs. Just put them in the right sub-directory in your war and the JSPs should be available automagically.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a servlet - or JSP - that has a mapping `*.xhtml` (other extension). Using the request URI it can do a dynamic include of the corresponding JSP from `pages`.

In servlet:

```
String pagesPath = "pages/" + ...;
request.getServletContext(pagesPath).getRequestDispatcher().include(request,
                                                                    response);
```

I doubt it is a good idea, as it does not add something: you might even need to adapt all JSPs (other extension). Or rename the JSPs to `.jspf`.

In general I use JSPs under WEB-INF/jsp or so; so they are not publicly accessible. And use a similar technique: creating a model in the servlet, and then to the view as JSP.